# iOS: dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue())

Tags: swift2

Pardon me for beginner's question. I'm following a tutorial, it has the following snippet.
I don't understand the point of `dispatch_async`, if you execute the block `self.webView...` on [the main queue on the main thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2) by calling `dispatch_get_main_queue()` anyway, why bother putting it inside `dispatch_async`?
Thanks

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            println(urlContent)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.webView.loadHTMLString(urlContent!, baseURL: nil)

            }

        }


    }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_async` is used to execute block on the other queue. It needs 2 parameters, first is the queue that it should execute in, second the code block.

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){...}
```

The reason why they use dispatch_async in your code is that the `...` code block will be executed in other queue (not in the main queue).

So if you want to execute `self.webView.loadHTMLString(urlContent!, baseURL: nil)` in the main queue, then you have to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){...}`.